# Django - Char ' and " in CharField are not rendered correctly in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have CharField with ' and " char in it. When I pass this field in a template with `{{ charfield }}`, it renders with `&quot` instead of " and `&#39` instead of '.

What is the source of this behaviour and how to avoid it?

Comment: This is correct behaviour for HTML templates. Are you sure you want to avoid it?

Comment: I store SQL query in the CharField to be included in javascript, so the ' and " are very important. Is there a safer solution to store SQL query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All variables coming into an HTML template are [auto-escaped](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) by default to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerabilities via maliciously crafted user input.

If you are completely sure that the contents of your variable are safe, you can turn autoescaping off at block level with a tag:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ charfield }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

or variable level with a filter:

```
{{ charfield|safe }}
```